# Apply text-overflow when no more space for nowrap-inline

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nowrap

I have a *inline-flex* container with two inner blocks that must expand (without wrapping).

In the second block there is another *inline-flex* container with two inner *inline-blocks* that **must never wrap** their content.

## What I need

Is to show the `text-overflow: ellipsis` when the width of the most-top container (`div.width`) is not enough for displaying all the inner blocks as `white-space: nowrap`.

The content of `div.width` **must never overflow** its container, in the case the content of the `a` link is too long.

## Snippet

```css
.splitbutton {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 4px solid violet;
}

.default {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-width: 0;
}

.default a {
/*  white-space: nowrap; */
}

.button {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container1,
.container2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 3px double green;
}

.width {
  border: 3px solid red;
  /*width: 350px;*/
    
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="width">
  <div class="container1">
    <span>Any kind of inline text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="splitbutton">
      <div class="default">
        <a href="#" title="Looooooooooooong text with many many spaces and letters">Looooooooooooong text with many many spaces and letters</a>
      </div>
      <span class="button">button</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Note

- *None of the present blocks can specify a specific fixed width!*
- The button must **always** stay visible (the ellipsis should eventually be applied to the `a` link element).

Comment: Why can't any of the blocks specify a width? You kind of need to specify a width for the `.default` block so that the overflow and text-ellipsis kick in.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that none of the blocks can specify a **fixed** width. They have to adapt as much as possible.